# How to print a field of a list under iteration in a view?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print a field of a list of answers from a view using django with no success (nothing is printed to the html), as follows:

```
<ul>
    {% for asnwer in answers %}
        <li>{{ answer.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm new to django, so I guess that I'm missing something which is pretty obvious. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo : asnwer instead of answer

Comment: LOL. A bit embarrassing, thanks :)

Comment: do you have something in the answers sequence?

Comment: how are you filling the context in your view? can you provide your call to `render` from your view?

Comment: @EvaldoBratti see Daniel's comment. The cause was a type

Comment: @AviranKatz  I thought it was just a typo error in your question and not in your real code ^^ sorry